# Can't generate .bbl file in TeXstudio

Tags: bibliographies

I'm using TeXstudio on OSX and try as I might I can't get a bibliography to compile.

The main doc of my MWE is `main1.tex`

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}
  This is a reference to reference \cite{citation123}.
  \bibliographystyle{plain}
  \bibliography{testbib}
\end{document}
```

My .bib file is `testbib.bib`

```
@book{citation123, 
author = "E. Jones", 
title  = "A Book Title", 
year   = "2015" }
```

When I run Tools>Bibliography, I get this error

```
Error: One command expansion invalid.
  Parent Command: bibliography
  Primary Command: bibliography
```

And then when I run pdflatex it gives the warning
    `No file main1.bbl.`

I walked through the steps described in the solution given for TeXstudio described here: [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations) 
but I always get the errors above. I've tried switching the default bibliography tool to bibtex, bibtex8, and biber; all give the same error. How do I make TeXstudio generate the `.bbl` file?

Comment: The `"` is missing after Jones.

Comment: Everything said in the biblatex-Editor question is not suited for you, it is a completely different (though related) matter.

Comment: Fixed the `"`, thanks. Same error.

Comment: in the example, you use the file name `\bibliography{testbib}`, but the error you show calls the file by another name" `testingbibilio.bbl`.  to be successful, those two names should be the same.  (it's not clear from your example where the latter name comes from.)

Comment: `testingbiblio.tex` is the name of the main tex document. I just changed the name to `main1.tex` to make this more clear. The name of my bib file is `testbib.bib`. I'm fairly certain that my tex and bib files don't need the same names (although I tried making them the same and got the same errors). The warning I get now is `No file main1.bbl`.

Comment: I have the same problem as you today. My problem is resolved by closing all the windows and reopen it.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you should run

```
latex main1.tex
bibtex main1
latex main1.tex
latex main1.tex
```

in a command window (terminal window). On my box, the example you have provided compiles like a charm. At least, you'll find out if the problem you see lies with the LaTeX installation or TeXstudio.

If the example works via command/terminal window, then you could change the Build & View process of TexStudio: `Options -> Configure TexStudio`, select the `Build Tab` and paste the line below at the Build & View textbox:

```
txs:///pdflatex | txs:///bibtex | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///pdflatex
```

Comment: Huh, that sure worked. It never would have occurred to me to try in the terminal, so thank you for that suggestion. I guess that means the problem is with TeXStudio...